# Unit tests: mock for BundleTable.Bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I am trying to do some unit tests for a custom helper created to render the scripts included in a bundle.

My problem is I need to **create a mock for BundleTable.Bundles** object, but I didn't find any relevant way how I can achieve this.

My method looks like here:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetBundleFilesCollection(string bundleUrl)
{
        bundleUrl = string.Concat("~", bundleUrl);
        var collection = new BundleCollection { BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(bundleUrl) };
        var bundleResolver = new BundleResolver(collection);
        IEnumerable<string> fileUrls = bundleResolver.GetBundleContents(bundleUrl);
        return fileUrls;
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I am using Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bundles` property on `BundleTable` is static and therefore not mockable (with Rhino Mocks).  Perhaps you can populate the Bundles collection with data that would satisfy your test?

There are commercial products that let you mock/stub static methods (I think TypeMock Isolator allows this).